# Programatically filling content controls in Word document (OpenXML) in .NET

Tags: c#, ms-word, custom-controls, openxml

I have a really simple word document with Content Controls (all text). 
I want to loop through the controls, filling them with values from a dictionary. Should be super simple, but something is wrong:

```
var myValues = new Dictionary<string, string>(); //And fill it

using (var wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputFile, true))
{
    MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart;

    foreach(SdtElement sdt in mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>())
    {
      SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault();

      if (alias != null)
      {
          string sdtTitle = alias.Val.Value;
          sdt.??? = myValues[sdtTitle];
      }
    }
    mainPart.Document.Save();
 }
```

How do I write my value into the document?
Do I need a CustomXmlPart?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do something like that, you'll need to write suitable content into the Sdt's SdtContent: a paragraph or a run or a tc etc depending on the sdt's parent element.

The alternative is to put the contents of your dictionary into a CustomXml part, and set up databindings on each content control which refer to the relevant dictionary element.   Word will then resolve the bindings when the docx is first opened (which is not much good to you if you expect your users to open it with something else).

Comment: Thanks, but still not sure how to solve the problem. I just want the most simple way to write to content controls in a docx.

Comment: This alternative listed here is a bad thing to do. After the i4i case Microsoft has changed office programs to remove any custom xml that they find.

Comment: @Scott, you're (understandably) confused. You are thinking of "custom xml tags", as opposed custom xml PARTS and databinding.  See further http://blogs.technet.com/b/gray_knowlton/archive/2009/12/23/what-is-custom-xml-and-the-impact-of-the-i4i-judgment-on-word.aspx

Comment: I think you are right, I am understandably confused here. So, looking into that link, we can still insert our own custom xml as a new part in a document and then bind that to content controls. Therefore, allowing two way updating between both the custom xml and the document itself? So, what we have lost is the ability to create custom xml tags? Am I correct here now?

Comment: Yep, now you've got it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
foreach (SdtElement sdt in mainPart.Document.Descendants<SdtElement>())
{
SdtAlias alias = sdt.Descendants<SdtAlias>().FirstOrDefault();

if (alias != null)
 {
  string sdtTitle = alias.Val.Value;
  Text t = sdt.Descendants<Text>().First();
  t.Text = "test";
 }
}
```